# Shuffle the Integer of the Object<Integer,String> in a List/ArrayList

Tags: java, list, shuffle

```
List<Data> list = new ArrayList<Data>();

public class Data{
    public int n;
    public String p;

    public Data(int N, String P) {
        n = N;
        p = P;
    }

}
```

How can i shuffle the Integer of the Object: Data. So the String stays at the same position, and the Integer get's shuffled.

Comment: What do you mean by shuffling?

Comment: you mean you want to suffle the order of the elements of `list`  ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. To have Data left where it is, but somehow shuffle it's number?

Comment: Example: List[1] = 1,"A" List[2] = 2,"F" List[3] = 3,"J" Shuffle -> List[1] = 2,"A" List[2] = 1,"F" List[2] = 3,"J"

Comment: There is no API method for this, afaik. You have to do it for yourself. What's the algorithm you proposed?

Comment: Perhaps it is more a problem of algorithms than API methods.

Comment: http://z0r.de/L/z0r-de_3714.swf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through `list` and store the `int` of each `Data` object in a separate list. Shuffle this list using `Collections.shuffle(...)`. Loop through this new shuffled list and set the `n` field of each corresponding member of `list` to the new random `int` found in the shuffled list.

Comment: This looks pretty promising, but I got for now 12 int/string in my list. So that means, it will need 12 Lists to accomplish this?

Comment: @user1621988 No, you need one separate list to store the ints and shuffle them.

Comment: Hmmm okay, I just can't see how "set the n field of each corresponding member of list to the new random int found in the shuffled list." is done.

Comment: @user1621988 Yes, his answer basically puts what I mentioned into code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably have to do it yourself:

```
for (int i = list.size(); i > 0; i--) {
    int j = (int)(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    int temp = list.get(i).n;
    list.get(i).n = list.get(j).n;
    list.get(j).n = temp;
}
```

The best you can do from java libraries is to first split it into two lists, one of ints and one of strings, then shuffle only the ints (using Collections.shuffle), then combine the two lists back into one list of Datas

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
List<Integer> ns = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.size());
for (Data data : list) {
    ns.add(data.n);
}
Collections.shuffle(ns);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Data data = list.get(i);
    int newN = ns.get(i);
    data.n = newN;
}
```

Note that it's best practice to use accessors `getN()` and `setN(int)` and make `Data.n` `private`.